# Why can't Tailwindcss override jQuery mobile css for <a>?

Tags: jquery, css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind css (with laravel) for a project together with jQuery mobile. The problem is that jQuery mobile overrides `<a>` tag's style.

This is the order in which the browser is loading the css files:

```
<!-- jQuery mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.css">

<!-- Tailwind css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
```

Even tho Tailwind css is the last css file loaded the `<a>` tags still have jQuery mobile style on them:

```
<a href="" class="text-white">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

The above `<a>` should be white ... yet it is still jQuery mobile's blue.

Why can't Tailwind css override jQuery mobile css?

P.S I tried editing `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    important: true,
    ...
};
```

But the problem with using `important: true` is that i can't use jQuery afterwards to change borders on click for example.

**EDIT** Screenshot in dev tools for styles:

[image]

Screenshot of html output:

[image]

Comment: I'd suspect this is not about what can or can't override things, but about selector specificity. Can you inspect what the HTML output is, and the styles and their application from developer tools?

Comment: oky, there it is, i see that jquery adds a few classes here and there :( to be honest i only want to use jquery mobile for the `tap` event which i find it really hard to do otherwise with pure jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why TailwindCSS can't override the applied jQuery mobile css is because it is losing the *CSS Specificity* battle. If you don't need all the styles jQuery mobile provides, it's better to remove it and base purely on TailwindCSS. I think you only need the jQuery mobile script for the `tap` event to work.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and it was indeed a specificity problem. Unfortunately jquery mobile will still add a few divs and classes so i decided to get rid of it completely and use another, much smaller, library that can handle the `tap` event.

Comment: An advantage of using Tailwind is it uses utility classes, eliminating the specificity issues we normally encounter with heavy frameworks where we need to override the default style declarations. Glad it worked out for you, Melody.